# Is it possible to declare a large underground area as a sovereign principality or any form of independent state?

Tags: international

If one were to happen upon a large cavern deep underground, are there any laws that dictate how deep underground a country's claim to land can be? Would it be possible to declare the area an independent country?

Comment: [Cuius est solum, eius est usque ad coelum et ad inferos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuius_est_solum,_eius_est_usque_ad_coelum_et_ad_inferos).  This is a (somewhat discredited) principle in property law, but I seriously doubt that any country would countenance a subterranean claim of sovereignty beneath its own sovereign territory.